# will antyhing screw up if I install VS 2010 Ultimate over Windows Phone Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the VS 2010 Windows Phone Express, but it does not contain features I need. Does anything can screw up if I install Ultimate over that version of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Both products should work fine side-by-side.